# Install ELK in centos

Tags: centos, elasticsearch

I install ELK on centos following below link. 
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-1-7-logstash-1-5-and-kibana-4-1-elk-stack-on-centos-7

But the problem is after the configuration,there is a error come to after the logging like below: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured any index yet so there's nothing Kibana can show you.  And in order to do this you must first feed some data to ES/Logstash.

Start by [creating an index and importing some data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/import-some-data.html), then enter the index name (`shakespeare`) in the field. Then you'll be able to run queries to analyze the data.

Alternatively, you can import some data via Logstash. There's a sample of Apache logs in the [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html), and you can [import them into ES via Logstash](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-tutorial-index-not-found-exception-solved/43786). Then enter `apachelogs-*` in the index field of Kibana.